# How to disable mesh color in sculpting mode?

Tags: modeling, sculpting

I joined four separate meshes with <kbd>Сtrl</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd> but in Sculpting workspace those meshes are showing in colors. 
How to disable it?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image]Change the color option in the "viewport shading" from random to something else. You have to be in solid mode to find this options. Click on the arrow on the top right of your viewport.

Comment: I'm sorry, but the solution you described is probably not appropriate for answering this question. This is another issue.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to say that "face sets" have to be disabled. That should desolve your problem.

Comment: thank you Yuri and Alex. Face Sets solved my problem.